# Resources are being inserted in the wrong order

Tags: java, maven

I'm using the `maven-assembly-plugin` to compile my JAR, here's the build config portion of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.hackclub.hackclubtools.HackClubToolsPlugin</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

One my dependencies happens to have a resource with the same name as one of my resources, `config.json`.

`maven-assembly-plugin` is compiling that dependency first and inserting its' resource first, meaning that when it gets to inserting my resources, I get this message:

```
[INFO] config.json already added, skipping
```

Is there any way to ensure that my resources take priority over the dependencies' resources?

Comment: Yes:  put your resource in a package.  There’s a reason the [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method looks in the same package as the class by default.  The whole point of packages is to prevent name collisions.

Comment: @VGR I want the file at the root of the JAR (see: outside a package), and this is where the conflict is occuring. A dependency wants the same thing, and it is being given priority for some reason.